# vb.net mysql combobox show tables

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, combobox

I am new at programming, and I'm working on a basic VB.NET application that allows the user to select, insert, update, and delete various data tables from MySQL.

The trouble I'm having is, I need to populate a combobox with all the table names from one specific database, so that the user can select which database table to work with.  I thought my code would work, but all I'm getting when I run the app is a blank combobox.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks so much in advance!

Code:

```
Private Sub TableList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TableList.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try

        command = New MySqlCommand
        dt = New DataTable
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter

        If (conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            setConnection()
        End If

        command.Connection = conn
        command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES"

        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        'adapter.Fill(dt)
        dt.Load(reader)

        TableList.DataSource = dt
        TableList.DisplayMember = "Tables_in_sampledata" 'What is displayed
        TableList.ValueMember = "Tables_in_sampledata" 'The ID of the row

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error1: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        reader.Close()
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: what error's do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SHOW TABLES`, use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I tried your query but it didn't do anything - I'm still getting a blank combobox. Even when I try basic sql queries like "SELECT * FROM 'databaseName'", I still get nothing.

Comment: @user1713373 you didn't specify the the data table of the dataset to set your datasource. ex, `TableList.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]`

Comment: It says "'tables' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataTable'".